# how to connect a number variable to dynamic text in actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, dynamic-text

i know this might be simple but i have been searching everywhere for a fix but i just cannot find it! 
i want to make something like a health #, so when you press whatever button the dynamic text # will go up or down. on my test project i have two layers, the first with the following code

```
var hp:Number = 100;
health.text = String hp;
```

hp being the variable, and health being the dynamic text. then i have the next layer with the button with:

```
function button(e:MouseEvent):void
{
hp -= 10;
}
```

without that second chunk of code, the dynamic text will appear, but once that is added it will disappear and the button is function-less.
how do i make this work??? once again sorry if this is a dumb question, i'm just very stumped.

Comment: For your text, you can do : `health.text = String(hp); `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
health.text = String hp;
```

use:

```
health.text = hp.toString();
```

and:

```
function button(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    hp -= 10;
    health.text = hp.toString();
}
```

Comment: it once again works up until putting the second code on the button. after putting that on the dynamic text disapears during testing it

Comment: Please attach FLA file.

Comment: You haven't registered an event handler. Above function "button" You must add this line `button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonHandler);` and rename a function "button" to `buttonHandler`.

Comment: awesome!! thank you so much!! just as a follow up question, what is the code to cap it off at a specific number? (im in the process of finally switching from 2.0 from 3.0, a lot of learning ha)

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand Your question. Can you write more clearly?

Comment: capping it off, so making it so it can't go any lower than 0

Comment: `if (hp - 10 >= 0) hp -= 10;` or `hp = hp - 10 <= 0 ? 0 : hp - 10;`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is good, but I wanted to point out that your original code was actually very close to being correct, you just needed parenthesis:

```
health.text = String(hp);
```

For most objects `String(object)` and `object.toString()` has the same effect, except that `object.toString()` throws an error if `object` is `null` (which could be desirable or undesirable, depending on what you expect it to do).